# Java SWT's equivalent of WPF's itemtemplate?

Tags: java, swt

Is it possible to display a list of items with a custom item template such as one can do in WPF, by specifying a Listbox Itemtemplate? Say i'm looking to display a list of Person instances, each with a name, age and a picture. Each listitem would have eq. a Label for name, age and an image area for the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use for this purpose Composite class, or some derivation of this class. Here is how i make it:

```
public class UiTransaction {

private String sFirstlabel;
private String sSecondlabel;

public UiTransaction(String sFirstlabel, String sSecondlabel) {
    this.sFirstlabel = sFirstlabel;
    this.sSecondlabel = sSecondlabel;
}

public Composite getComposite(Composite composite, int style){
    return new SpecificComposite(composite,style);
}
class SpecificComposite extends Composite {

    public SpecificComposite(final Composite composite, int style) {
        super(composite, style);
        Label lblFirstlabel = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        lblFirstlabel.setBounds(10, 10, 275, 15);
        lblFirstlabel.setText(sFirstlabel);

        Label lblSecondlabel = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        lblSecondlabel.setBounds(10, 31, 275, 15);
        lblSecondlabel.setText(sSecondlabel);

    }

}
```

}

After that you can use ScrolledComposite for displaying this custom Composite.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid implementing a listbox-like behavior yourself ? Referring to the fact, that Swt's List only takes Strings as input elements.

Comment: i didn't find, another implementation :(. Take a look at ScrolledComposite, it is some sort of listbox for Composites.